# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement zipfile (from versions: )

Tags: python, pip, python-zipfile

I used pip install zipfile, and error went out:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement zipfile (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for zipfile
>
> Addition Info: pip 18.1 from
>   /Users/xxxx/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python
>   2.7)

Comment: Are you on python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need to install it. [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) is in the [Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/). `import zipfile` should work just fine on both [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/zipfile.html) and [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html).